# Design decoder with pass transistor

Tags: transistors, decoder

I'm trying to design a \$3*8\$ decoder using pass transistors.

I found an implementation with TG on the web (transmission gate) as the following picture, but I can not design one with pass transistors. I need help to get some ideas about the design. what about \$2*4\$ or \$1*2\$?

[image]

Comment: By "pass transistors" do you mean BJTs? Because a FET is also a transistor, in common usage.

Comment: @jonk I mean pmos and nmos transistors together, a transistor that can pass 1 easily or it can pass 0 easily

Comment: common discrete mosfets have a body diode which will complicate matters greatly. Also, the picture is wrong in the first column.

Comment: pass transistor logic (PTL) it seems is the name assigned to gates with reduced FET logic to switch between nodes rather than rails.

Comment: What you are calling a "pass transistor" is exactly what the given schematic calls a "transmission gate".

Comment: So you are asking which FETs are redundant (hmm new to me)  invented by Kawasaki in '97

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  yes, I mean something like that.

Comment: I dont see any redundant FETS for a MUX. decoder , sorry  but then I imagine there are books written on this subject

Comment: What are you "passing" - ie is there an analog end to end connection, or do you simply want a digital output signal controlled by address lines. This makes a large difference to a solution.